# Python: Dictionary being returned by func as string? What the heck am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, string, function, dictionary, return

I'm generating a dictionary in a function and then returning this dictionary. I can't seem to access the returned dict as a dictionary though despite it being the correct format.. It is treating the data as a string only, ie i can print it but can't print d.keys() or d.items() What the heck am I doing wrong?????

**data when printed as a str()**

{1: '214902885,214902909', 2: '214902910,214902934', 3: '214902935,214902959', 4: '214902960,214902984', 5: '214902985,214903009', 6: '214903010,214903034', 7: '214903035,214903059', 8: '214903060,214903084', 9: '214903085,214903109', 10: '214903110,214903139'}

**Error when I try to print d.items() or d.keys()**

```
print bin_mapping.keys()
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Once I have returned the dict from a function do I have to redefine it as a dictionary? I'd really appreciate some help as I'm super frustrated :/

Thanks,

**As suggested here is the code.. Function I'm calling to return the dictionary first..**

```
def models2bins_utr(id,type,start,end,strand):
  ''' chops up utr's into bins for mC analysis'''
  # first deal with 5' UTR
  feature_len = (int(end) - int(start))+1
  bin_len = int(feature_len) /10
  if int(feature_len) < 10:
   return 'null'
   #continue
  else:
  # now calculate the coordinates for each of the 10 bins
   bin_start = start
   d_utr_5 = {}
   d_utr_3 = {}
   for i in range(1,11):
    # set 1-9 first, then round up bin# 10 )
    if i != 10:
     bin_end = (int(bin_start) +int(bin_len)) -1
     if str(type) == 'utr_5':
      d_utr_5[i] = str(bin_start)+','+str(bin_end)
     elif str(type) == 'utr_3':
      d_utr_3[i] = str(bin_start)+','+str(bin_end)
     else:
      pass
     #now set new bin_start
     bin_start = int(bin_end) + 1
    # now round up last bin
    else:
     bin_end = end
     if str(type) == 'utr_5':
      d_utr_5[i] = str(bin_start)+','+str(bin_end)
     elif str(type) == 'utr_3':
      d_utr_3[i] = str(bin_start)+','+str(bin_end)
     else:
      pass
  if str(type) == 'utr_5':
   return d_utr_5
  elif  str(type) == 'utr_3':
   return d_utr_3
```

**Calling the function and trying to access the dict**

```
def main():
  # get a list of all the mrnas in the db
  mrna_list = get_mrna()
  for mrna_id in mrna_list:
   print '-----'
   print mrna_id
   mrna_features = features(mrna_id)
   # if feature utr, send to models2bins_utr and return dict
   for feature in mrna_features:
    id = feature[0]
    type = feature[1]
    start = feature[2]
    end = feature[3]
    assembly = feature[4]
    strand = feature[5]
   if str(type) == 'utr_5' or str(type) == 'utr_3':
    bin_mapping = models2bins_utr(id,type,start,end,strand)
    print bin_mapping
    print bin_mapping.keys()
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the function that's returning that data? And the code that calls it?

Comment: I was going to but it's alot of code... Maybe a truncated version.. I'll get on it.

Comment: check that 'null' is not ever returned ...

Comment: Ick, 1 space indents? How do you manage to *read* this stuff, let alone maintain it?

Comment: Thanks georgesl !! I overlooked a very simple error.. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You return a string early on:

```
bin_len = int(feature_len) /10
if int(feature_len) < 10:
    return 'null'
```

Perhaps you wanted to raise an exception instead here, or *at the very least*, return an empty dictionary or use `None` as a flag value.

If you use `None` do test for it:

```
bin_mapping = models2bins_utr(id,type,start,end,strand)
if bin_mapping is not None:
     # you got a dictionary.
```

Comment: @BartoszKP: but why expect to be able to call `.keys()` on it?

Comment: Yes, your suggestion is a better solution. I was just interpreting OP's attempt. Beginners tend to think locally, so probably when writing this line OP wasn't focused on how this result will be used :)

Comment: Thanks guys.. Yes that's the prob. I'm still getting my head around stylistically making my code in chunks... Waht a stupid mistake :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what `return 'null'` is supposed to achieve. My guess is that once in a while, you call the function with the wrong parameters and get this string back.

I suggest to throw an exception instead (`raise Exception('Not enough arguments')` or similar) or to return an empty dict.

You should also learn about `repr()` because it gives you more information about an object which makes debugging much easier.

Comment: "You should also learn about repr() because it gives you more information about an object which makes debugging much easie"  Thanks I'll check that out.